# Telerik Reporting and EF5 DbContext

Tags: entity-framework, telerik, entity-framework-5

I've downloaded the latest (v6.2) trial version of Telerik Reporting but cannot figure out how to hook it up to my Entity Framework model.

I've added an `EntityDataSource` to the designer but this requires a `typeof(ObjectContext)` which I don't have.

Looking at the example code from the Telerik website it appears I might be able to cast from DbContext to ObjectContext at runtime but this does not (that I can see) enable me to build a report at design time.

[Telerik - EntityDataSource Component](http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/entitydatasource.html)

Is it possible to get Telerik Reporting to work with Entity Framework 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually got this on the Telerik forum

> Hi Peter,
>
> The EntityDataSource component is meant to bind only to ObjectContext (so that it is compatible with the old .NET 3.5 version of Entity Framework) and it does not support DbContext directly. In that case you have two options. The first and the better one is to work with the ObjectDataSource because you are already working with POCOs and it will be very easy. The second one is to extract the ObjectContext from the DbContext wrapper. It is not as simple as using a property, but can be valuable if you insist on working with the EntityDataSource. More information you can find in this Accessing ObjectContext Features from EF 4.1 DbContext article.
>
> We would have DbContext support in mind for subsequent version of the product (most probably once we drop support for older versions of the .NET framework).
>
> Kind regards,
>   Steve 
>   the Telerik team

After much trial and error I got the ObjectDataSource working with my EF POCOs but couldn't get anything on the screen. I then stumbled across a video that showed setting a property of the report to the ObjectDataSource and voila!

However, then the `ICollection<Related>` entities would not resolve. Maybe I could have got it working with more trial and error but the official forum was unresponsive as was SO on this topic.

Not enough examples and explicitly built to work seamlessly only with old versions of the framework.

---

**update**

I've just finished the [pluralsight course on Telerik Fundamentals](http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/telerik-reporting) and it is fairly simple to use Entity Framework with Telerik Reporting, not directly with the DbContext but with specific objects that wrap the calls to EF, returning classes/IEnumerables etc.

Good course. For me it changed Telerik Reporting from a mystery to simplicity. Bargain.

Comment: But EF already has objects that 'wrap' calls. They are DbSet objects.

Comment: @ProfK yes they do but the `DbSet` does not wrap the creation and management of the `DbContext` so you need to handle that yourself. If you use `ObjectContext` you can bind the report directly to the context object and Telerik handles the rest for you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that now DbContext is supported, so no ObjectContext generators nor casting will be needed to use Telerik Reporting with EF 5 (and probably EF 6 beta, though I haven't tested it yet).

Comment: I got this error when trying to bind to EF context: Data binding directly to a store query (DbSet, DbQuery, DbSqlQuery) is not supported. Instead populate a DbSet with data, for example by calling Load on the DbSet, and then bind to local data. For WPF bind to DbSet.Local. For WinForms bind to DbSet.Local.ToBindingList().